# Tachanun when making aliyah to Israel?

Tags: tachanun, aliya-laaretz, simchah-joy-happiness, zionism

Is aliyah to Israel an occasion for which one does not recite Tachanun?  Is there a difference of minhag on this, or is there a uniform answer (yes, it is a special enough occasion to refrain from saying Tachanun vs. no, it is a regular Tachanun day)?  If there is a difference, is it dependent upon hashkafic differences (zionist/anti-zionist), or halachic differences (based on writings of Rishonim, Acharonim, etc.)?

Comment: Can you explain why you think there might be different Minhagim?

Comment: @SethJ Because a lot of things in Judaism have different minhagim.

Comment: @SethJ - Good edit, thx!

Comment: are you talking about while making the trip to Israel or living in Israel? Because if you're talking about the trip, Tachnun is omitted while traveling (I can't remember the source right now, and I don't remember if this is a universal custom, but I think it is)

Comment: @Menachem - Care to [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) where the source is?

Comment: @AdamMosheh: I'm not going to ask it as a question now, if you want to, go ahead. I found this on google books, http://books.google.co.cr/books?id=p2qC-G9wR1EC&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=tachanun+travel+danger&source=bl&ots=HPFHWFRvlp&sig=A7MdvzEcyyMNauHTKt65M88kns4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PeYqUOjbMOa26QHo-oCgDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false - I'm not quite sure what sefer he's quoting from (you can see the footnotes a couple pages later)

Comment: @AdamMosheh: It's footnotes 42 and 43 - in the body he says that many chassidim don't say tachanun when traveling and says the reason is connected to Berachot 28B, which says that a person walking in a dangerous place prays an abbreviated prayer.

Comment: @AdamMosheh: The reason I heard (and have to find a source for) is that traveling is a time of danger, so we don't mention our sins while traveling, so as not to give The Satan any ideas.

Comment: It seems to me a regular Tachanun day - why do think Tachanun is dependent upon where you're physically located, as opposed to being dependent upon a particular time?  Tachanun is not said with regard to time-bound mitzvos.  I.e. the holydays, Bris, the Chasan etc.  All based on a particular event, not really based on your location - for example, would the Jews not say Tachanun after leaving Eretz Yisrael because of the persecution of the Romans?  They got away with their lives intact?

Answer (score 3):

It's orally reported (I heard it on a Rabbi Rakeffet mp3) that when Rabbi Moshe Feinstein was asked by Bnai Akiva about Hallel on Yom Ha'atzmaut, he replied: "nu, if it's a yomtov for you, then say Hallel; personally I don't."

That may be the spirit you'll find here.